# cursor within a cursor?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, etl

is it possible to define a cursor inside a cursor?

I have two cursors with columns, which I then subtract from each other via a minus statement.
However, I also need a cursor after the minus statement, since I need to iterate the columns. Each column should be added to a create view script so that it creates all columns.

I need the cursor for the variable "all". Does anyone have an idea? It doesnt work with this code..
Please do not look at the content like "xy". The values are not adjusted yet. It is only a testscript.

Here is my script:

```
DECLARE CURSOR itemsone
FOR 
    SELECT table_name, column_name 
    FROM table1
    WHERE table_name LIKE 'xy'; 
    
DECLARE CURSOR itemstwo
FOR 
    SELECT table_name, column_name 
    FROM table2
    WHERE table_name LIKE 'xy';
    
    
DECLARE test_sql VARCHAR(500);
---
FOR item AS itemone DO
    all = SELECT column_name FROM table1 WHERE table_name = 'xy' AND column_name like 'z'
          MINUS 
          SELECT column_name FROM table2 WHERE table_name = 'xy';

    test_sql= CONCAT(CONCAT('CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_', 'TEST'), 'AS ( SELECT');
    
    FOR a AS all DO 
        test_sql = test_sql + CONCAT(a,', ');
    END FOR;

-- MORE TO FOLLOW
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to nest Cursors as many times as you want.
Below is an example where I nest 3 cursors:

```
Declare Cursor_1 CURSOR FOR Select (...)

Open Cursor_1 
Fetch Next From Cursor_1 Into (...)
While(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
Begin

    Declare Cursor_2 CURSOR FOR Select (...)

    Open Cursor_2 
    Fetch Next From Cursor_2 Into (...)
    While(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    Begin
        
        Declare Cursor_3 CURSOR FOR Select (...)

        Open Cursor_3 
        Fetch Next From Cursor_3 (...)
        While(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
        Begin

            (...)
            Fetch Next From Cursor_3 Into (...)

        End
        Close Cursor_3 
        Deallocate Cursor_3 

        Fetch Next From Cursor_2 Into (...)

    End
    Close Cursor_2 
    Deallocate Cursor_2 

    Fetch Next From Cursor_1 Into (...)

End
CLOSE Cursor_1  
DEALLOCATE Cursor_1
```